# Как принять данные с дальномер через Bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Всем привет. У меня есть дальномер, которое передает информацию о дальности через bluetooth. И мне нужно прочитать эти данные в моем приложении. Я попытался связать свое устройство с дальномером из Bluetooth Settings, но всегда получаю «Отказано в доступе» (вероятно, дальномер запрограммирован таким образом). Прошу подскажите как могу я прочитать эти данные ?

Comment: Запросить документацию у производителя дальномера, оттуда и узнаете как что читать и если это возможно в принципе.

Comment: Точно возможно у меня есть еще и ветромер, работает точно тем же принципом. Но производител вместе с устройством дал ещё и SDK

Comment: Вот именно, возможно там какой-то закрытый протокол обмена или ключ зашит в SDK.

Comment: Я прочитал немного и оказывается данное устройство является Low Power Bluetooth. То есть там совсем другой принцип работы.